# How to remove sliced line from pie high chart if there there is only one object in data

Tags: charts, highcharts, pie-chart

How to remove sliced line from pie high chart if there there is only one object in data. I want to see complete circle when there is one data coming. Right now it shows one slice line in circle. I don't want it to be there.

```
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            slicedOffset: 0
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            {
                name: 'Firefox',
                y: 44.2,
                selected: true,
                sliced: false
            },

        ]
    }]
```

[Screen shot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R54A5.png)

Comment: it would be great if you inlcude screen-shot

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by setting the [`borderWidth`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.borderWidth) to 0 and [`borderColor`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.borderColor) to `null`. The default is 1:

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderColor: null
    }
},
```

Comment: Thats the answer. Thanks.

Comment: setting border width to 0 wouldn't completely remove it. there would still be white space available, as mentioned in the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.borderWidth). have to set borderColor to null. example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qmfz4em4/)

Comment: @RahulSharma, true. I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: you wouldn't need to set border width if border color is null.